# insert a record with value 0.1, 0.2 and when any flag changed it should start with 1.0,1.1.. and so on

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a requirement while creating an initial quote, the number should start with 0.1, and then after that each number is added by +1 (i.e. 0.2) and so on...

In between if any flag is changed, then the number should start with 1.0, 1.1.. and so on...

How can I implement this?

Comment: are then only 10 possibilities before a flag?

Comment: If you're asking for a sort of auto increment column then it might not be possible.  However, it might be possible to generate this identifier at the time when you query.  Update your question with some sample data.

Comment: insert into test_sample values ('S1','Sample1',0.1)
/
insert into test_sample values ('S1','Sample2',0.2)
 
insert sample_stage:
insert into sample_stage values ('S1','N')
/
insert into sample_stage values ('S2','N')
/
insert into sample_stage values ('S3','N')
/
insert into sample_stage values ('S1','Y')
/

whenever stage_flag changes to 'Y' in sample_stage table, the record should start inserting with version 1.0,1.1,1.2 and so on....in test_sample table for particular sample_number.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I have created some data as per your sample.

```
    create table test_sample ( v VARCHAR(2), n NUMBER );

           create table sample_stage as 
           SELECT 'S1' s, 'N' stage_flag FROM DUAL UNION ALL
           SELECT 'S2' s , 'N' stage_flag  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
           SELECT 'S3' s, 'N' stage_flag FROM DUAL UNION ALL
           SELECT 'S1' s, 'Y' stage_flag FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
           SELECT 'S2' s, 'N' stage_flag FROM DUAL UNION ALL
           SELECT 'S3' s, 'N' stage_flag FROM DUAL UNION ALL
           SELECT 'S1' s, 'Y' stage_flag FROM DUAL ;
```

Here is the Pl/SQL code.

```
           DECLARE
             incr NUMBER;
           BEGIN
             INSERT
             INTO test_sample VALUES
               (
                 'S1',
                 0.1
               ) ;
             FOR stg IN
             ( SELECT * FROM sample_stage ORDER BY ROWID
             )
             LOOP
               IF stg.stage_flag = 'N' THEN
                 SELECT n+0.1
                 INTO incr
                 FROM test_sample
                 WHERE ROWID IN
                   ( SELECT MAX(ROWID) FROM test_sample
                   );
               ELSE
                 incr := 1.0;
               END IF;
               INSERT INTO test_sample VALUES
                 ( stg.s , incr
                 );
             END LOOP;
           END;
           /
```

Data   got inserted in the following form.

```
 SELECT * FROM test_sample;


       S1   0.1
       S1   0.2
       S2   0.3
       S3   0.4
       S1   1
       S2   1.1
       S3   1.2
       S1   1
```

Please Share your feedback.Thanks